# using MathLink for communication with external program from my C program without Mathematica

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp

I have a compiled program with MathLink.
I want to use it from other C program, without Mathematica being involved at all.
If i create my program with MathLink and connect to this external program, than i get number packets with number of functions:
`DefineExternal ["funcname[]" , "{ }" , 89 ]`
that registers these functions as external in Mathematica.
How could i, from my C programm, call analog of Mathematica `CallPacket[89,{}]` function to call "funcname".
Sending directly `MLPutFunction(lp, "funcname")` to this external application does not seems to be working, as, i suppose, it is intended to be used only for communication from external program with Mathematica, or?

Comment: Now that is an absolutely fascinating question.

Comment: I must admit I was very unclear as to the meaning of your question until I saw your comment on the corresponding question on SO. Anyway, you cannot use `MLPutFunction(lp, "funcname")`--functions must be called by ordinal as *MathLink* programs don't have access to the *Mathematica* interpreter. Instead use `MLPutFunction(lp, "CallPacket", nargs+1); MLPutInteger(lp, ord); /* put any arguments on the link here */ MLEndPacket(lp);`. See the book *MathLink: Network Programming with Mathematica* by Chikara Miyaji and Paul Abbott for more information.

Comment: Sorry--the arguments should be in a `List`, not given as a sequence. (That's why this is just a comment: no time to give a properly debugged answer now. I'm sure you'll be able to figure it out for yourself--and when you get a working solution, feel free to self-answer.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thank you very much Oleksandr, it works. There should be empty List even when no arguments.

```
MLPutFunction(lp, "CallPacket", 2);
MLPutInteger(lp, 89);
MLPutFunction(lp, "List", 0);
MLEndPacket(lp);

MLGetReal(lp, &dp);  //return value
```